# Events on subview backbone render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I'm trying to render multiple subview that depends on another father view.
The problem is coming when make a render function on children subviews. This subview shows correctly but the events associated has no initialized and no working.

This is the code.

```
 onSuccess : function(data) {
            this.asignView(this.subView1, '#div1', data.data1);
            this.asignView(this.subView2, '#div2', data.data2);

        },
```

...........

And this is the code of subviews..

```
 events : {
    'clickT' : 'clickT',
},

 render : function(model) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        model: model
    }));
    return this;
},

clickT: function(){
```

}......

The method assigned to subviews is....

```
asignView : function(view, selector, options) {
    view.setElement(this.$(selector)).render(options);
},
```

Well, how do I solve the problem?

Comment: You want the clcickT to be executed when subView clicked? First, is clcickT a typo? you event maping is direct to `clickT` not `clcickT `.

Comment: Oh sorry, its a error type. The function is clickT. I have the correct name in my code. This is not the problem. Thanks 'fuyushimoya'.

Comment: So when you click on the subview, the `clickT` not get executed?

Comment: No, its no responds on the event.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I try to copy some of your codes to jsfiddle, it seems to work, can you point out anyother difference between our codes?

```js
var asignView = function(view, selector, options) {
    view.setElement(this.$(selector)).render(options);
};

var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<span>A subView with id <%= model.id %>!</span>'),
    events: {
        'click': 'clickT'
    },
    render : function(model) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({
            model: model
        }));
        return this;
    },
    
    clickT: function() {
        alert('Clicked');
    }
});

var subView1 = new SubView()
,subView2 = new SubView();

asignView(subView1, '#div1', {id: 1});
asignView(subView2, '#div2', {id: 2});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi¡ Thanks for your answer. I'm lookinging for any diference between our codes, but its equals. I try wirh the method  this.delegateEvents() in the subviews, but it doesnt work for me... some ideas?

Comment: Did you use chrome dev-tool to inspect there's any error happened?

Comment: Ah! change `'clickT' : 'clickT'`  to `'click' : 'clickT'`, that may be the problem.

Comment: No, it isnt the problem... the problem its relationated with the subviews and delegateEvents in backbone, Whe the subview has render, the #element _dom of the subview does not exists, and the events asociated are not recognized, but I dont know how resolve it.

Comment: But in http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html, its `setElement` Do bind the events to the input element for you. And, still better change 'clickT' : 'clickT' to 'click' : 'clickT' if that is another typo.

Comment: Yes, setElement should be correctly, but the events isnt asociated with the subview .

Comment: Is `'clickT' : 'clickT'` is your code or just another typo? Because html don't have the `clickT` event.

Comment: no no, my code has this event, it was another type error. I is 'click #input : clickT'

Comment: Well, then i think you should use the dev-ver of Backbone, open dev-tool, set breakpoint at View's `setElement`, `_setElement`, `delegateEvents` and `delegate`, to see whats really going on.

Comment: Wait! `click #input` is listen to element which has and id `input`, do you sure that's what your subview has? If you're specifying the `input` element in the subview, use `click input:  clickT` instead